# Interpreting the minimum of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a basic question in linear algebra, that I need to figure out:

**Suppose that $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Is there any interpretation for the following quantity?
$$\min_{v\neq 0} \frac{|v^\top A v|}{v^\top v}$$**
For example, if $A$ is a non-negative definite matrix, then it denotes the smallest eigenvalue of $A$, and if $A = B^\top B$ for some matrix $B$, then it denotes the smallest singular value of $B$. But what about if $A$ is just assumed to be symmetric and nothing else? Note that in this case, if we ignored the absolute value, then the above quantity once again represents the lowest eigenvalue of $A$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

with symmetric but indefinite $A,$ your minimum is always zero. For example, take
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The eigenvalues are nonzero, but if $v = (\sqrt 2, 1)^T$ causes $v^T A v = 0$

Comment: ahh! that's nice...